# smbclient script putting several files with variable

Tags: linux, shell, samba

I want to put a whole directory that contains pdf files on another server with a smbclientscript. My script:

```
    #Set variable for reports
variable=`ls | grep pdf`

smbclient -U "server\user"%pw //some/direc/tory/bla/bla << Commands
cd to/another/dir
put $variable
exit
Commands
```

It actually works, but the problem ist that it can only copy the first file that is listet bei ls | grep pdf.
For the other Files the shell responds with file:command not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution be myself:

```
cd /directory/with/files/to/copy
#Set Variable
reports=$(ls *)
for i in $reports ; do

    smbclient -U "srv\User"%pws //some/dir/bla/bla/bla << Commands
    cd another/dir/etc
    put $i
    exit
    Commands
    done
```

Thanks!

Comment: This will cause a problem when one of your filename has spaces. for example, this file `this is a test.pdf` will lead to 4 files `this` `is` `a` `test.pdf`, this is because when bash expands, it will use the value of  `IFS` variable as a separator, the default value of `IFS` is <tab><space><newline>, so it will cause a problem when filename contains space. To solve this problem you can use `IFS=$(echo -e '\t')` to set IFS with <newline>. and in `for` block, Be sure sround `$i` with double quote.

Answer (score 1):

In bash

```
variable=`ls |grep pdf`
```

will get a string variable with STDOUT, not an array. It's no what you want.

Maybe `xargs` will help you. You can do as follows, but not an elegant solution I think.

```
ls | grep '.pdf$' |xargs -I{} smbclient -U "server\user"%pw //some/direc/tory/bla/bla -D 'to/another/dir' -c "{}"
```

Comment: Sorry for my typo. It's `-I` not `-i`. I do know how to use `subclient`, but `xargs` should solve your problem, and it's a great tool, you can see how it works using `man xargs` in *UNIX. You can also try this command `ls | grep '.pdf$' |xargs -I{} smbclient -U "server\user"%pw //some/direc/tory/bla/bla -D 'to/another/dir'` -c "{}"